# How to find the most frequent value in a column using np.histogram()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram

I have a DataFrame in which one column contains different numerical values. **I would like to find the most frequently occurring value specifically using the np.histogram() function.**

I know that this task can be achieved using functions such as column.value_counts().nlargest(1), however, I am interested in how the np.histogram() function can be used to achieve this goal.

With this task I am hoping to get a better understanding of the function and the resulting values, as the description from the documentation (https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) is not so clear to me.

Below I am sharing an example Series of values to be used for this task:

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,10,size=100))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Make data
np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 10, size=100))
# Make bins
bins = np.arange(data.min(), data.max() + 2)
# Compute histogram
h, _ = np.histogram(data, bins)
# Find most frequent value
mode = bins[h.argmax()]
# Mode computed with Pandas
mode_pd = data.value_counts().nlargest(1).index[0]
# Check result
print(mode == mode_pd)
# True
```

You can also define `bins` as:

```py
bins = np.unique(data)
bins = np.append(bins, bins[-1] + 1)
```

Or if your data contains only positive numbers you can directly use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```py
mode = np.bincount(data).argmax()
```

Of course there is also [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html):

```
import scipy.stats
mode = scipy.stats.mode(data)[0][0]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. So how would you define creating the bins for a set that has n unique values? I see you added +2 to data.max - would that work for any number of bins?

Comment: @Maciej In the first example I am assuming `data` is integer, now `np.arange(data.min(), data.max() + 1)` would be range of values in `data`, but you need an extra value for the upper limit of the last bin, hence `np.arange(data.min(), data.max() + 2)`. When using `np.unique`, you already get the sorted array of values, so you just need to add one more for that upper limit, I added the largest value plus one, bit it can be any value as long as it is larger than the largest value in `data`. The logic is the same independently of the number of different values in `data`.

Comment: @Maciej Of course the other option is to put the bin edges at decimal places, [as mathfux suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60187587/1782792).

Comment: Just one more question. I understand that hist holds the counts for each bin, or the size of each bin. Bin_edges holds the bins. How come do I get the value of interest from np.argmax(hist), if this holds the counts, not the values?

Comment: @Maciej You're right, `hist` holds the number of values in `data` that fall within each bin. So, if the first bin is `[1, 2)` and there are three `1` in `data`, then `hist[0]` will be `3`. Now, `argmax` gives you the index of the largest value in `hist`, so the bin corresponding to that position will tell you the most frequent value. For example, in the previous example, if `argmax` were `0`, then the corresponding bin is `[1, 2)`, so the most frequent value would be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with:

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=np.arange(0.5,10.5))
result = np.argmax(hist)
```

You just need to read documentation more carefully. It says that if `bins` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` then first bin is `[1, 2)`, second is `[2, 3)` and third is `[3, 4)`.

We calculate which amount of numbers are in bins `[0.5, 1.5)`, `[1.5, 2.5)`, ..., `[8.5, 9.5)` specifically in your problem and choose index of the maximum one.

Just in case, it's worth to use

```
np.unique(data)[np.argmax(hist)]
```

if we are not sure that your sorted data set `np.unique(data)` includes all the consecutive integers 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: For this to be correct, you would have to use `bins=np.arange(-0.5, 10.5)`, so the first bin corresponds to `0`, otherwise the value returned by `argmax` is going to be shifted by one (or you could add one to the result). About `np.unique`, I'm not sure that's right, if `data` is `[1, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5]` then `argmax` will give `4` but `np.unique` will return `[1, 2, 5]`, it would give an error.